# Typemock and Dependency Injection, still use interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I see some good design benefits in DI and not just good testability design. So even though I have Typemock and could unit test without IOC, I still prefer constructor DI. I think it's a great way to quickly discover the dependencies of a class.

Now I'm wondering should I keep using interfaces as the type parameter in the constructor. They are very easy to create using Resharper, but it's still a type that I don't really need.

A quick example of what I mean

```
public interface IService
{
    void Method();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void Method()
    {

    }
}

public class ClassThatUsesDI
{
    public ClassThatUsesDI(IService service) **or** (Service service) 
    {

    }
}
```

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

With interfaces, you have the option to replace the actual type being used at runtime, based on configuration. You *can* do that with classes too, if you inherit from them, but it's easier still with just interfaces.

My advice is to stay with the interfaces.

And to be honest, I write my services the other way around. First I update the interfaces, because the "world" I'm in at that point is more limited, and makes me think more about what I can really do in the interface, and then I update the concrete types afterwards.

Comment: Writing the interfaces first makes good sense, but when I look at my last project, replacing the type by configuration would be YAGNI for me.